# Flutter: Crash in release mode for android V2 upgrade

Tags: android, flutter

I upgrade my android to V2 and now my app crash at the splash screen in release mode.

This is the error I see

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException: ensureInitializationComplete must be called after startInitialization
       at io.flutter.embedding.engine.loader.FlutterLoader.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterLoader.java:292)
       at io.flutter.view.FlutterMain.ensureInitializationComplete(FlutterMain.java:8)
       at io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.onCreate(FlutterFirebaseMessagingService.java:10)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3542)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap4(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1786)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6938)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

I am using Flutter 1.22.4

Please let me know how to fix this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Did you configure firebase startup correctly? Check that the firebase_core package has been installed and verify that the firebase startup is correct.

Comment: This works on iOS but fail in release mode on Android.. Works in debug mode.

Answer (score 0):

try adding

```
FlutterMain.startInitialization(this);
```

before super.onCreate in MainActivity

For Example

```
class MainActivity : FlutterActivity() {

  override protected fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    FlutterMain.startInitialization(this) // This Line
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for help... but the documentation ask me remove  the block of code in MainActivity ...https://github.com/flutter/flutter/wiki/Upgrading-pre-1.12-Android-projects